# Is it possible to get a list of all months using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Using vanilla JS, is it possible to get an array of months? For example:

`['January', ..., 'December']`

While libraries like moment.js exist and make sense to use rather than reinventing the wheel, sometimes it's desired/necessary to implement in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 7):

[`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) can produce month names so it's possible to generate an array of 12 items and map each item's index (0 - 11) to month names.

```js
const months = new Array(12).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
  return new Date(`${i + 1}/1`).toLocaleDateString(undefined, {month: 'long'})
});
console.log(months);
```

The code above logs the array of months:

```
[
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
]
```

Here's how it works:

- `new Array(12)` initializes a new array of length 12
- the array can't be mapped until it has some items defined, so `.fill(0)` initializes all items to `0`
- `.map(...)` maps all 12 `0`s of the array
- `(_, i) => { ... }` is a function that ignores the first parameter (which is the item itself, in each case it will be `0`) and only makes use of the index, which will go from `0` to `11`
- `` new Date(`${i + 1}/1`) `` initializes a new date object with the date in the format MM/DD where the month is a 1-based index and the day of the month is always `1`. Setting the day is necessary because otherwise it default's to today's date and if it happens to be >28 the month may roll over to the next one (eg if today is 7/31 but i==2, then the date will be initialized with February 31, which doesn't exist, so the Date object just produces a day in May instead)
- `.toLocaleDateString(undefined, {month: 'long'})` is where the magic happens. The object contains a [`formatMatcher`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Parameters) object, which controls how the date is formatted when written out as a string. The `month` property is set to `'long'` so that the full month name (eg `"July"`) is produced. Fun fact: the first argument is undefined so that it doesn't overwrite the user's default locale. This is awesome because a user in France would see the month names in French automatically:

`["janvier", "février", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "décembre"]`

If you want to keep the months in English, just set this parameter to `'en'`.

---

If it helps, here's the same code rewritten to use older JS grammar:

```js
var months = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var d = new Date((i + 1) + '/1');
  months.push(d.toLocaleDateString(undefined, {month: 'long'}));
}
console.log(months);
```

Comment: Downvoter(s), please let me know if there's anything I could improve.

Comment: did you just answer your own question 5 seconds after posting it?

Comment: @zv_ I asked/answered at the same time since I searched here for this question/answer but didn't find it. I figured it out myself and thought others may be interested in the solution.

Comment: I wasn't the one who originally downvoted you, but you should know about [StackOverflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topics), where that sort of thing should live. Your answer is undoubtedly well-written, but it really exemplifies "*the* problem" that is so often discussed at meta.stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. I'll look into moving the answer there.

Comment: I would definitely move it over there. The content you wrote it too high-quality to be confined to some little question that might not even break the top-20 links on Google Search. 

Unrelated, but I seem to remember there being some localization object that was recently standardized that could do this task (listing months) as well?

Comment: `[...Array(12).keys()].map(i => new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {month: 'long'}).format(Date.UTC(1, i + 1, 1, 1, 1)) )` was object & method I discussed above. I am not sure about it's shortcomings outside of being browser specific (if any). It might be worthwhile to include in your documentation entry.

Answer (score 3):

I think using `setMonth` is both more efficient and easier to understand than creating a date from a concatenated string.

```js
const months= [];
const d = new Date();
for(let month = 0; month < 12; ++month) {
   d.setMonth(month);
   months.push(d.toLocaleString(undefined, {month: 'long'}));
}

console.log(months);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `new Date(0, month)` if you prefer the look of it. Less efficient than `setMonth` as it builds 12 Date objects rather than re-using one, but slightly shorter.

```js
const months = (locales) =>
  [...Array(12)].map((_item, index) =>
    new Date(0, index).toLocaleString(locales, { month: "long" })
  );

console.log({ en: months("en"), es: months("es") });
```

Output

```js
{
  en: [
    'January',   'February',
    'March',     'April',
    'May',       'June',
    'July',      'August',
    'September', 'October',
    'November',  'December'
  ],
  es: [
    'enero',      'febrero',
    'marzo',      'abril',
    'mayo',       'junio',
    'julio',      'agosto',
    'septiembre', 'octubre',
    'noviembre',  'diciembre'
  ]
}
```